# Creating multiple sum fields based upon criteria in another field in MS access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table like this,

I**D-------Amount-----------Transaction Code----------Branch Code--------Value Date**

1--------1523--------------------35-----------------------------99------------------2014/01/01

2--------14---------------------91-----------------------------10------------------2014/01/01

3--------789--------------------35-----------------------------14------------------2014/01/02

4--------5000-------------------85-----------------------------99------------------2014/01/02

5--------6778-------------------35-----------------------------5------------------2014/01/03

6--------8000-------------------20-----------------------------5------------------2014/01/03

7--------5646-------------------20------------------------------99------------------2014/01/03

etc. It will have millions of rows. What I have been trying to do is create a report for each Branch Code.

In that I want to have a sum of the 'amount' grouped by value date for a number of different transaction codes. For example: Report for Branch code '99'would look like

**Value Date**--------**Sum of Transaction Code '35'**--------------**Sum of Transaction Code '20' AND '85'**
2014/01/01 -------------- ???     -------------------------------------------------???

2014/01/02 -------------- ???     ------------------------------------------------???

2014/01/03  ------------  ???     ------------------------------------------------????

etc. This would only sum the amounts where the branch code was 99

And then I want to create a number of different reports with the same structure but for a different branch code. Is this possible?! I am really struggling here. Would be eternally grateful for some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use conditional aggregation.  In MS Access, that would look like:

```
select valuedate,
       sum(iif(transactioncode = '35', amount, 0)) as trans_35,
       sum(iif(transactioncode = '20' or transactioncode = '85', amount, 0)) as trans_20_85
from tablelikethis
where branchcode = '99'
group by valuedate;
```

Comment: Hi, The Sum I'm looking for is from the 'amount' field. Grouped by value date, and then for the transaction code's like you have it. This code wouldn't capture that would it?